# configured oracle goldengate DML replication both are oracle database

Tags: oracle, oracle-golden-gate

I had configure oracle D ML replication using oracle golden gate successfully but is there any query to check source and target is in sync or not or how to verify IT.

Answer (score 1):

No replication tool has the functionality to check if the database is in sync. The idea of asynchronous replication is that it is never fully in sync - the target is always late compared to the source database. Only fully synchronized disk replication allows a full in sync copy of the data.

You might want check if the "not recently changed" data is the same using a compare-every-row technology. Oracle has a product called Veridata which can do the job.

You might also want to check if the replication stream is working (it is not stopped). But this check does not check if the data is in sync. Someone might modify the target data and you might not be able to check that. The heartbeat technology just checks if the replication stream is not broken. OGG 12.2 has special build in commands for that.

Please check:

- [ADD HEARTBEATTABLE](https://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/c1221/gg-winux/GWURF/add-heartbeattable.htm#GWURF1238) command for ggsci
- [ENABLE_HEARTBEAT_TABLE](https://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/c1221/gg-winux/GWURF/enable_heartbeat_table-disable_heartbeat_table.htm#GWURF1258) parameter for processes